# Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key copy activity fails

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

Data factory Copy activity fails when copy the delta table from databricks to storage account gen2

Details

ErrorCode=AzureDatabricksCommandError,Hit an error when running the command in Azure Databricks. Error details: Failure to initialize configurationInvalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key
Caused by: Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: provide more information on how everything is configured

Comment: If i add fs.azure.account.key.<Storgae account name>.dfs.core.windows.net<space><accesskey> at cluster creation level then,Copy activity runs successfull.But have doubt here how can we call secrets at cluser mode level.Created secret scope at databricks level.

Comment: you can refer to secrets in the cluster configuration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secrets#syntax-for-referencing-secrets-in-a-spark-configuration-property-or-environment-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above error mainly happens because the staging is not enabled. We need to enable staging to copy data from delta Lake.

***Go to Azure Databricks inside cluster -> advance option and edit spark config as per the below format.***

```
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net <Access Key>
```

After that you can follow this  [**official document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-databricks-delta-lake?tabs=data-factory#prerequisites) it has detail explanation about copy activity with delta lake.

you can refer this [**Article**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/388994/azure-databricks-adf-connectivity-issue-delta-tabl.html) by  RishShah-4592

Comment: You are 100% correct. As we can not use sensitive info in cluster level, how can i replace with secret scope and keys for access keys..

Answer (score 1):

I think so you can pass the secret as below:

```
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net {{secrets/<secret-scope-name>/<secret-name>}}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Edit the cluster,
fs.azure.account.key..dfs.core.windows.net{{secrets//}}

Its working fine now...Able to copy data from delta lake table to adls gen2