# ADF Copy data from Azure Data Bricks Delta Lake to Azure Sql Server

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to use the data copy activity to extract information from azure databricks delta lake, but I've noticed that it doesn't pass the information directly from the delta lake to the SQL server I need, but must pass it to an azure blob storage, when running it, it throws the following error

```
ErrorCode=AzureDatabricksCommandError,Hit an error when running the command in Azure Databricks. Error details: Failure to initialize configurationInvalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key Caused by: Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key
```

Looking for information I found a possible solution but it didn't work.

[Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key copy activity fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72724911/invalid-configuration-value-detected-for-fs-azure-account-key-copy-activity-fail)

Does anyone have any idea how the hell to pass information from an azure databricks delta lake table to a table in Sql Server??

These are some images of the structure that I have in ADF:

[image]

In the image I get a message that tells me that I must have a Storage Account to continue

These are the configuration images, and execution failed:

Conf:
[image]

Fail:
[image]

[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: Wouldn't ADF be the one passing credentials per se?  Azure Databricks would use the set of credentials to access the data sitting in ADFSgen2 and you would have ADF use the same credentials to access the Delta Lake table and then have another set of credentials to have write access to Azure SQL Server.  

By any chance are you trying to access an AzDB Delta Lake table sitting in DBFS vs. a separate ADLSgen2 account?

Comment: What happens is that when using the copy activity to transfer data from delta lake to a db, it tells me that I must have configured a linked service for a gen2 storage account, I have added the images to the original question to try to be a little clearer , thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem was the following:

Correct the way the Storage Access Key configuration was being defined:

in the instruction: spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key..blob.core.windows.net

The following change must be made:
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.
storageaccountname.**dfs**.core.windows.net

Comment: I met similar issue. How do you update the config change?

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone have any idea how the hell to pass information from an azure databricks delta lake table to a table in Sql Server??

To achieve Above scenario, follow below steps:

**First go to your Databricks cluster Edit it** and under **Advance options >> spark >> spark config** Add below code if you are using blob storage.

```
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.<storageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net <Accesskey>
spark.databricks.delta.optimizeWrite.enabled true 
spark.databricks.delta.autoCompact.enabled true
```

[image]

After that as you are using SQL Database as a sink.
`Enable staging` and give same blob storage account linked service as `Staging account linked service` give storage path from your blob storage.

[image]

And then debug it. make sure you complete Prerequisites from official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-databricks-delta-lake?tabs=data-factory#prerequisites).

**My sample Input:**

[image]

**Output in SQL:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it keeps failing: "ErrorCode=AzureDatabricksCommandError,Hit an error when running the command in Azure Databricks. Error details: Failure to initialize configurationInvalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key
Caused by: Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key".     I will complete the question with images of the configuration and failures

Comment: I have a question, Accesskey which data specifically is it? I want to be sure that it is taking the correct data

Comment: We cannot directly copy data from Azure databricks delta lake to SQL database we have to use Azure blob storage or ADLS gen 2 as intermediator so as you are using blob storage you have to mention blob storage account name and access key of it in this format `spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.<storageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net <Accesskey>`

Comment: We have already made all the configurations indicated here in stack, we have even created a mount point for the storage account, but the error remains the same, any ideas????

Comment: Are you using adls ?

Comment: that's right, we are using ADLS, and we have already made the SPARK configurations in the cluster